# Can't get tag text after trigger Selenium click function

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

`http://211.21.63.217:81/ticket_online.aspx`

I crawl the website movie list data, I can get movie name、movie time successfully.

Then I want to crawl each movie tomorrow movie time, so I click ever tomorrow `<span />` by using selenium.

I make sure Selenium has clicked each `<Span />` also I have set `time.sleep` and check the tag root is correct, but tomorrow `movieTime` is empty in the result.

I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta  
import time

# like 07/02
tomorrowDate = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = tomorrowDate.strftime('%m/%d')
afterTomorrowDate = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=2)
afterTomorrow = afterTomorrowDate.strftime('%m/%d')
print(tomorrow)
print(afterTomorrow)

class CenturyasiaxinbeiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'CenturyasiaXinbei'
    allowed_domains = ['www.centuryasia.com.tw', '211.21.63.217:81']
    start_urls = ['http://211.21.63.217:81/ticket_online.aspx']

    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/motogod19/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('http://211.21.63.217:81/ticket_online.aspx')

    def parse(self, response):
        firstHtmlNodes = response.xpath('//article[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Time_box"]//section[@class="tickets_movie_time_box"]')
        for firstHtmlNode in firstHtmlNodes:
            # print(firstHtmlNode)
            # Today
            movieCnName = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./div[@class="tickets_movie_time"]/div[@class="tickets_times"]/div[@class="tickets_times_t"]/div[@class="times_title"]/text()').get()
            movieEnName = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./div[@class="tickets_movie_time"]/div[@class="tickets_times"]/div[@class="tickets_times_t"]/div[@class="times_title_en"]/text()').get()
            movieTime = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./div[@class="tickets_movie_time"]/div[@class="tickets_times"]/div[@class="tickets_date"]/div[3]/div/div[@class="tickets_date_csbox"]/div/ul/li/text()').extract()

            print(movieCnName)
            print(movieEnName)
            # sort the movie time
            print(sorted(movieTime))
            print('\n')

        time.sleep(2)
        allSpanDate = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='{}']".format(tomorrow))
        for spanDate in allSpanDate:
            ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(spanDate).perform()
            spanDate.click()
            time.sleep(1)

        tomorrowResponse = HtmlResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        secondHtmlNodes = tomorrowResponse.xpath('//article[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Time_box"]//section[@class="tickets_movie_time_box"]')

        for secondHtmlNode in secondHtmlNodes:
            # Tomorrow
            movieCnName = secondHtmlNode.xpath('./div[@class="tickets_movie_time"]/div[@class="tickets_times"]/div[@class="tickets_times_t"]/div[@class="times_title"]/text()').get()
            movieEnName = secondHtmlNode.xpath('./div[@class="tickets_movie_time"]/div[@class="tickets_times"]/div[@class="tickets_times_t"]/div[@class="times_title_en"]/text()').get()
            # movieTime = secondHtmlNode.xpath('./div[@class="tickets_movie_time"]/div[@class="tickets_times"]/div[@class="tickets_date"]/div[3]/div/div[@class="tickets_date_csbox"]/div/ul/li/text()').extract()
            movieTime = secondHtmlNode.xpath('./div[@class="tickets_movie_time"]/div[@class="tickets_times"]/div[@class="tickets_date"]/div[3]/div[@class="tickets_date_cts"]/ul')
            # tickets_date_cts
            print(movieCnName)
            print(movieEnName)
            # sort movie time
            print(sorted(movieTime)) # Empty is here
            print('\n')
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: As per the code there is a difference in `firstHtmlNode.xpath` and `secondHtmlNode.xpath`. `div` tags are missing in second one. `/div[3]/div/div[@class="tickets_date_csbox"]/div/ul` in firsthtmlnode and `/div[3]/div[@class="tickets_date_cts"]/ul` in second one.

Comment: And you have stopped all `ul` in `secondHtmlNode.xpath`.

Comment: Yes, It's my type error, actually I try movie time for `secondHtmlNode.xpath` is the same as `firstHtmlNode.xpath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath, it works for both `movieTime = firstHtmlNode.xpath()` and `movieTime = secondHtmlNode.xpath`.

```
.//div[@class='tickets_date_cts']/ul/li
```

Comment: Thanks you so much ! Why your code is working ? Because it's more specify for Scrapy ?

Comment: @Morton - You are welcome. That xpath locates the timings irrespective of the date. Thats it.